# Auto-indent javascript code in Vim on save

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation

I am using the awesome `vim-go` plugin for coding in Go with vim. (https://github.com/fatih/vim-go)

The feature that I love is the auto-indent on save. I'd like to get the same behavior for javascript files. Do you know any way to easy replicate this in js?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a general autoformatting plugin for vim called [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat) which integrates the js-beautifier (the engine behind the online application http://jsbeautifier.org/) and more.

It provides an `:Autoformat` command, which you can bind to the `BufWrite` event like so

```
au BufWrite * :Autoformat
```

**EDIT**
For if you're only interested in indenting your file (not full-fledged formatting): vim-autoformat falls back to auto indenting your file if js-beautify is not installed.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need a plugin to auto indent in vim. As soon as you open the file in vim, press these keys:

```
gg
```

Your cursor should move to the beginning of the file. And then type this:

```
=G
```

which is basically saying, "remove trailing spaces from the cursor position to the end of the file". Happy coding!

Comment: Awesome answer :)

Comment: Mentioned here too - https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat#how-to-use